# Draft.js—get editor content as html

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I am starting with Draft.js right now, so I might miss some important things here. But as the title says: I would like to get the full html generated by the editor. Right now I have:

```
this.state.editor.getCurrentContent() // Object ContentState
this.state.editor.getCurrentContent().getPlainText() // no html tags
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of say, `draftjs` is not designed for HTML editing, although it use HTML to rendering the editor. For now there is no any perfect solution to export the `ContentState` to HTML.

The [draft-js-export-html](https://github.com/sstur/draft-js-export-html) may help a lot if you not do much customization to `draftjs` blocks.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick so far… The current Application I am on is a bit wired, serverside rendering would be the best solution, but, well, this can probably happen in the far future… Maybe I have to use another Editor, but for now, that is perfect!